# how to get previous step values in next step in drupal multi step form?

Tags: forms

How to get previous step values in drupal in the next step in a multiform. I want to display the values other than drupal_set_message(). I want to use these previous values in other function in the next step.

```
function form_example_wizard_previous_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $current_step = &$form_state['step'];
  $form_state['step_information'][$current_step]['stored_values'] = $form_state['values'];
  if ($current_step > 1) {
    $current_step--;
    $form_state['values'] = $form_state['step_information'][$current_step]['stored_values'];
  }
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

function form_example_wizard_next_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  $current_step = &$form_state['step'];

  $form_state['step_information'][$current_step]['stored_values'] = $form_state['values'];


  if ($current_step < count($form_state['step_information'])) {
    $current_step++;
    if (!empty($form_state['step_information'][$current_step]['stored_values'])) {
      $form_state['values'] = $form_state['step_information'][$current_step]['stored_values'];
    }
    else {
      $form_state['values'] = array();
    }

    // Force rebuild with next step.
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
    return;
  }
}


function form_example_wizard_personal_info($form, &$form_state) {
   $form = array();
  $form['pagenumber']= array(
      '#title' =>t('Page Number'),
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#required' => TRUE
      );
  $form['wordscount']= array(
      '#title' =>t('Words count'),
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#required' => TRUE
      );
  $form['calcvalue'] = array('#type' => 'hidden', 
  '#value'=>'test' );
  return $form;
}


function form_example_wizard_location_info($form, &$form_state) {
  $form = array();
  $form['quoteprice'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Editing Your Document Will Cost'),
    '#value'=>$quoteval,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: I need to pass hidden filed value in next step.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to send data from one from to other.

1. You can use session
2. You can also pass value in url

Example of pass by value

```
function register_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
$name = $form_state['values']['name'];
$age = $form_state['values']['age'];

$data = array(
    'query' => array(
         'name' => $name,
         'age' => $age,
        )
    );

$form_state['redirect'] = array('/success', $data);
}
```

here is a link you can refer for send data

https://www.drupal.org/node/2064545

Comment: I am using this $form_state['rebuild']

Comment: Here is a example you can refer http://davidsonj.com/blog/how-create-multi-step-form-drupal-7

Comment: please check my code on above.. and help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `$form_state['storage']` for this. Checkout the [linked blog](http://bryanjones.us/article/custom-multi-step-forms-drupal-7).

Comment: I am not getting how to apply $form_state['storage'] here

Comment: Instead of setting the step info in `$form_state['step_information']` use `$form_state['storage']`.